# SFAuthorizationPluginView identifying "BACK" button

Tags: macos, plugins, authorization, sfauthorizationpluginview

Does anyone who has experience with SFAuthorizationPluginView know how to identify between the user pressing "Cancel" and "Back".  My problem is that **SFButtonTypeCancel**  is identical to **SFButtonTypeBack**, hence a *switch* statement will fail at compile time, and an *if* statement will not recognize the difference.

This is not a problem when displaying the login screen as "name and password", but when displaying as "List of Users", handling the "Back" as "Cancel" makes the login window restart instead of shifting nicely to the list.

Regards
Alan

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, the login window has a CANCEL button when Fast-User Switching, and a BACK button when in the login screen, therefore I managed to identify between the two buttons, by the following code:

```
    CFStringRef str_console_uname;
    uid_t       uid;
    gid_t       gid;

    // get console username
    str_console_uname = SCDynamicStoreCopyConsoleUser(NULL,
                                                      &uid,
                                                      &gid);
    if (!str_console_uname ||
        [(NSString *)str_console_uname compare:@"loginwindow"] == 0)
    {
        /* BACK BUTTON */
    }
    else
    {
        /* CANCEL BUTTON */
    }
```